# Split a file by commas

Tags: python, list, file, split

I have a python task what requires me to do the following,

***Create a program to: ***

1. search this data file by surname to retrieve and display the details for a contact
2. search this data file by date of birth (dd/mm/yyyy) to retrieve and display all contacts with a birthday in a particular month
3. Add a new persons details to the file

   ```
   file = open ("c:\ABOOK.txt", "r")

   myfile = (file.readline())

   mywordlist = myfile.split()


   mylength= len(mywordlist)# reads how long it is
   print(mylength)
   count = 0 # counts 
   afound = 0 # counts 
   s_name = input("Enter a surname to be found:") 
   textfile=(file.readlines()) 
   print(textfile[0])
   mwl = textfile[0].split(",")
   mwl1 = textfile[1].split(",")
   mwl2 = textfile[2].split(",")
   mwl3 = textfile[3].split(",")
   mwl4 = textfile[4].split(",")
   while(count<len(textfile)):
       print(textfile[count])
       count = count + 1
   print(mwl,mwl1,mwl2,mwl3,mwl4)
   print(textfile.split(","))
   ```

the file is broke by ","'s and here's an extract of the notepad; its six lines long.

```
Jackson,Samantha,2 Heather Row,Basingstoke,RG21 3SD,01256 
135434,23/04/1973,sam.jackson@hotmail.com
Vickers,Jonathan,18 Saville Gardens,Reading,RG3 5FH,01196 
678254,04/02/1965,the_man@btinternet.com
Morris,Sally,The Old Lodge, Hook,RG23 5RD,01256 
728443,19/02/1975,smorris@fgh.co.uk
Cobbly,Harry,345 The High Street,Guildford,GU2 4KJ,01458 
288763,30/03/1960,harry.cobbly@somewhere.org.uk
Khan,Jasmine,36 Hever Avenue,Edenbridge,TN34 4FG,01569 
276524,28/02/1980,jas.khan@hotmail.com
Vickers,Harriet,45 Sage Gardens,Brighton,BN3 2FG,01675 
662554,04/04/1968,harriet.vickers@btinternet.com
```

Comment: Please format your code as you actually have it, indentation is very important in Python, more importantly what is your actual question? What specifically is not working...

Similarly for your extract please format it exactly how it appears.

Comment: Im on a laptop and as ive recently woken up im a bit shakey and the touchpad is a bit sensitive, its formated to how i have it, and im stuck on getting it to have the whole text file splited by ","'s  and then i need to get so i can find that in the file and also add peoples data to the file. i dont need to to be fully done just need some guidance, unless you want to fully complete it go ahead i cant stop you in doing so

Comment: So your code is not indented after the first while?

Comment: You can check `len(textfile)` to be sure it has at least 5 elements. If it has not, you should read the documentation of `split` function (`textfile.split(",")` might be what you are looking for).

Comment: yes, im making sure the small things work before i piece together the puzzle. just easier for me to be honest

Comment: @Nuageux when i do the (textfile.split(",") it tells me a list cannot be split by split or something along them lines.

Comment: Ok. Can you fix your indentation (After the first While it should be indented). And also provide the 6 lines so we can run completly your code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is basic solution for the first two parts of your program note you can improve this a lot such as not hard coding the file name, striping the new line characters etc. (Issues that would mean if you used this exact code you will not get 100%) but I will leave that as a task for you:

```
import sys

def find_record_by_surname(input_surname):
    found = False
    with open("ABOOK.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            surname = line.split(',')[0]
            if surname == input_surname.title():
                found = True
    return found

def return_details_by_surname(input_surname):
    details = []
    with open("ABOOK.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            details = line.split(',')
            if details[0] == input_surname.title():
                break
    return details

def find_record_by_month_of_birth(input_month):
    if len(input_month) != 2:
        input_month = "0" + input_month
    found = False
    with open("ABOOK.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            month = line.split(',')[6].split('/')[1]
            if input_month == month:
                found = True
                break
    return found

def return_details_by_month_of_birth(input_month):
    if len(input_month) != 2:
        input_month = "0" + input_month
    details = ""
    with open("ABOOK.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.split(',')[6].split('/')[1] == input_month:
                details = details + line
    return details

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Menu Choices")
    print("============")
    print("1: Search contacts by surname")
    print("2: Search contacts by month of birth")
    print("3: Add a new contact to ABOOK.txt")
    print("4: Exit")
    choice = input("Enter your choice: ")
    while choice != "4":
        if choice == "1":
            input_surname = input("Enter a surname you would like the records for from ABOOK.txt? ")
            if find_record_by_surname(input_surname):
                print("The record with the entered surname was found in ABOOK.txt")
                print("The details for that contact are:")
                print(return_details_by_surname(input_surname))
            else:
                print("The record with the entered surname was not found in ABOOK.txt")
        if choice == "2":
            input_month = input("Enter the month of birth (1-12) you would like the records for from ABOOK.txt? ")
            if find_record_by_month_of_birth(input_month):
                print("The details for the contact(s) with the entered month of birth are: ")
                print(return_details_by_month_of_birth(input_month))
            else:
                print("No record with the entered month of birth was found in ABOOK.txt")
        if choice == "3":
            # TO-DO code for adding a new contact
            print()
        print("Menu Choices")
        print("============")
        print("1: Search contacts by surname")
        print("2: Search contacts by month of birth")
        print("3: Add a new contact to ABOOK.txt")
        print("4: Exit")
        choice = input("Enter your choice: ")
    print("Goodbye!")    
    sys.exit(0)
```

**ABOOK.txt file used:**

```
Jackson,Samantha,2 Heather Row,Basingstoke,RG21 3SD,01256135434,23/04/1973,sam.jackson@hotmail.com
Vickers,Jonathan,18 Saville Gardens,Reading,RG3 5FH,01196678254,04/02/1965,the_man@btinternet.com
Morris,Sally,The Old Lodge, Hook,RG23 5RD,01256728443,19/02/1975,smorris@fgh.co.uk
Cobbly,Harry,345 The High Street,Guildford,GU2 4KJ,01458288763,30/03/1960,harry.cobbly@somewhere.org.uk
Khan,Jasmine,36 Hever Avenue,Edenbridge,TN34 4FG,01569276524,28/02/1980,jas.khan@hotmail.com
Vickers,Harriet,45 Sage Gardens,Brighton,BN3 2FG,01675662554,04/04/1968,harriet.vickers@btinternet.com
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much it works!!, next thing for me to do after getting helped with this is to try and find out how to alter this piece to make it search for the date of birth and then how to add someone to the files!! life saver you are sir

Comment: For the date a simple way would be to use a nested `if`s where you first store the date: `date = line.split(',')[6]` then use split again to find out if the month is matches the users inputted month: `month = date.split('/')[1]`.

Comment: What i've done is use your code and altered it to give me the date, i cannot seem to get this to work ive waited 24 hours till i asked again to see if i could work it out my self,

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f92c629ec8828ac9ba95ac31d81571ad

Comment: @ChristopherAllum I will see what I can do :)

Comment: @ChristopherAllum See updated answer for bare minimum version of part 2 of your assignment, I will not be helping you with part 3. Ask another question for that if you get stuck.

Comment: I passed Thanks, i totally forgot about stack overflow, im now year 11 still going through Comp Science. I struggle on the visual side but im really hunkering down on the code. Many thanks you saved me from alot of detentions. :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to split a string just use

```
detail_arr = string.split(',')
```

detail_arr will now be an array with all your different rows.

Here is an example in code:

```
>> str =  "Jackson,Samantha,2 Heather Row,Basingstoke,RG21 3SD,01256135434,23/04/1973,sam.jackson@hotmail.com"
>> str.split(',')
['Jackson', 'Samantha', '2 Heather Row', 'Basingstoke', 'RG21 3SD', '01256135434', '23/04/1973', 'sam.jackson@hotmail.com']
```

every >> is a line executed in the console.

In order to add details add them to your arr and then do:

```
str = ''.join(map(lambda x: x + ',', details_arr))[:-1]
```

Str will now be all your array seperated by commas and you can write it to your file.

In your code, you dont want to split the data by spaces as done on line 3 but by comma.

Also you have a while without an exit clause so youll be stuck in an infinite loop.

Your code should look as follows:

```
file = open ("c:\ABOOK.txt", "r")

data = file.read()

data_rows = data.split(',') //every 8th row it will start a new entry (7,15,23...)
```

Now, searching by Surname will be searching in rows 0,7,15...
Searching by birthdate will be on rows 6,14,22..
You can figure all the rows out. You can create a counter to see what contact youre looking at:

```
c = 0 //counter of entry
for i in xrange(len(data_rows)/8):
    if data_rows[i+row_number] == val: // row_number depends on what youre trying to match
        print ''.join(data_rows[c:c+8])
    c += 1
```

Now you can tell what entry matches the value.

Comment: how and where would this be implemented in the line of code, my it teacher hasn't really taught me much he just gave me it and told me to crack on. most of this is foreign to me. and as my teachers strict as well he'd also sanction me if its not to his standards

Comment: @ChristopherAllum Better?

Comment: thanks :) this helped me understand